# Keep html formatting of outlook email body in access form

Tags: html, ms-access, outlook

I currently have a linked table in access that points to a folder in outlook. I want to be able to manipulate these emails inside of access. I'm able to do this, but the only problem is the formatting of the email body field (called contents in the linked outlook table) is lost. I have the text box set as rich text, but everything is converted to plain text. Is there any workaround here to keep the original formatting including tables that is seen in the email? I used the wizard in access to link the outlook folder.

Comment: I doubt you can. Access rich text fields support only a small subset of HTML, e.g. no tables.

Comment: Do you know if you are able to add an outlook object inside of an access form then?